# xbindkey delete suggestion makes the shift key constantly pressed

Tags: shortcut-keys, xbindkeys

I have xubuntu on an Acer c720. This means that there is no delete key on the keyboard. After googling for a while i find that everyone has solved this by adding

```
"xdotool keyup shift+BackSpace; xdotool key Delete; xdotool keydown shift" 
shift+BackSpace
```

to the xbindkeysrc file and then `$ xbindkeys &`. For some reason, when i then press shift+BackSpace, it's like the shift key is constantly pressed in(i.e. All Caps, left and right buttons while in text marks the text, when clicking on the desktop the roll down box appears).

Since the shift key is allways pressed in it's kind of hard to test, but i think the BackSpace key also permanently functions as the Delete key, but i might be wrong about that.

Why is this happening? Why doesn't anyone else seem to have this problem? How do i fix this so that shift+BackSpace acts like a delete key?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Install `sudo apt-get install xautomation` and try this two lines: 1) `"xte 'key Delete'"` and 2) `Shift+Mod2 + BackSpace` and give me a ping with `@A.B.`

Comment: @A.B. I tried that(but i used mod4 since i didn't find mod2) and nothing happened when i pressed the buttons, do i have to install xte?(is this pinging? I'm new at this site)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem. I use the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install xvkbd           #to install the package
xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Delete]'  #to activate the correct key
```

instead, it works great. I still don't know why the other method doesn't work for me.

Comment: You should mention that the package `xvkbd` is not installed by default.